# Getting null value while unmarshalling an XML

Tags: jaxb

Can anyone please help me with this JAXB unmarshal issue?

So, this is the file employee.xml I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<parent>
  <anotherchild1>Another</anotherchild1>
</parent>
```

and this is the Parent.java class which has JAXB annotation:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package XMLToObject;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author Gauravb
 */
@XmlRootElement 
public class Parent {
    private String child;
    private String anotherchild1;

    public String getAnotherChild1() {  
        return anotherchild1;  
    }  
    public void setAnotherChild1(String child) {  
        this.anotherchild1 = anotherchild1;  
    }




}
```

And this is XMLToObject.java file which I am using:

```
    package XMLToObject;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Gauravb
 */
import java.io.File;  
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;  
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;  
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;  

public class XMLToObject {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
     try {    
            File file = new File("employee.xml");    
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Parent.class);    
         System.out.println("Reading....."+file.getAbsolutePath());  
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();    

            Parent p = (Parent) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

            //System.out.println("Child:"+p.getChild());  
            System.out.println("Another Child:"+p.getAnotherChild1());  

          } catch (JAXBException e) {e.printStackTrace(); }    

}  
}
```

Now, my issue is when I run XMLToObject.java file, then I see following:

```
Reading.....C:\xxxxxx\employee.xml
Another Child:null
```

So, can anyone please let me know what can be the reason behind the value as null?

Please note:
1.  I am a newbie in JAXB
2. I am using Netbeans editor while running the code
3. I do NOT have XSD for the XML and dont want to use any for my learning
4. I do NOT want to use MOXy for now, this is something I will learn next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgot to add @XmlElement annotation in the binding class  Parent.java as below

```
    @XmlElement
    private String anotherchild1;
```

Comment: I did that now, but still the same issue. However, I was under impression annotating @XmlElement is optional in case of JAXB and should be used if I want to change names etc, else JAXB takes the annotation from parent (@XmlRootElement) only.

Comment: Because your getters and setters is not matching  the actual xml element (note a camelcase C in setter)  . So you need to add @XmlElement for proper binding

Comment: I am Sorry, I am not sure If I understand, but my setter does not have a camelcase C. All are lowercase c only (like in the XML):

public void setAnotherChild1(String child) {  
        this.anotherchild1 = anotherchild1;  
    }

However, I did add the xmlElement on the variable and it worked. So, can you please help me understand on why on variable, adding @XmlElement worked but did not work on my getter?

Comment: for filed anotherchild1 , setter should be setAnotherchild1  instead setAnotherChild1()

Comment: I removed @XmlElement and tweaked the method to this, which also worked, thanks for your help. I have marked this question as answered. I never realised that JAXB also relies on exact element name in getter and setter.

public void setanotherchild1(String anotherchild1) {  
        this.anotherchild1 = anotherchild1;  
    }